# How to add an Area to an ASP.NET MVC project using Visual Studio 2019 for Mac?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-mac

I'm going through a Udemy ASP.NET Core 3 MVC course, and I'm trying to add an Area to my project. I understand that on PC, this has been moved to 'New Scaffolded Item', where the Area option shows up, but on the Mac, this option is 'New Scaffolding', and 'Area' isn't an option.

So how do I add a new Area to my ASP.NET MVC project? Google has failed to return anything specifically for Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read the following link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Add some more information. Links change and get deleted over time. Include the minimum information needed for the question and keep the link as reference.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your need. In macOS, you haven't powerful tool like Visual Studio for Windows. You need use command line.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=netcore-cli

You will belong to 1 of 2 cases: Has existing Identity database schema or not. In any case, you can use command line. Use something like this:

```
dotnet tool install -g dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity --useDefaultUI
dotnet ef migrations add CreateIdentitySchema
dotnet ef database update
// ...
```

The fist: Install tool by

```
dotnet tool install -g dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator
```

the second, use it

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity --useDefaultUI
```

**Other trick:** You can create a new project in PC (even remote Windows server), generate everything you want, then push it to Git sever or copy these files manually in file system. Simple and pragmatic.

Comment: Thanks. I downloaded the tool and ran the commands, but the Identity Area is already installed. How would I go about creating a new Area called Customer using the above commands? `dotnet aspnet-codegenerator customer --useDefaultUI` didn't work.

Comment: No parameter `customer` . Seemly you need customize table `AspNetUsers` of ASP.NET Core Identity.

Answer (score 0):

Add `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design` package to the project as a NuGet package reference

install / update dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator

```
dotnet tool install/update -g dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator
```

then run following command

```
 dotnet aspnet-codegenerator area <AreaName>
```

to know more details kindly go through following [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/tools/dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator?view=aspnetcore-7.0)